# IE8 Style Does not support setProperty method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Getting this error on this line of code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.setProperty("background-color", "#D19000", "important");
```

[image]<kbd>Object doesn't support property or method 'setProperty'</kbd>

---

Only in IE8 , go figure, anyone have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Perhaps try `... [0].style["backgroundColor"] = "#D19000"`

Comment: A polyfill can be used `CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.setProperty = function (name, value, priority) {
    this[name] = value;
  };` as `CSSStyleDeclaration` is here, seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older versions of Internet Explorer you will need to use this syntax:

```
elem.style.backgroundColor = "#D19000";
elem.style.color = "red";
```

Note that any property that is hyphenated will need to be in camelCase.

Comment: how do you add the !important property to the backgroundColor ?

Comment: You should be able to set it as: `backgroundColor = "#D19000 !important"` if I recall correctly.